# SQL: Query to Search All possible words

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form with an input box where the user can specify their names, the names may be two or more words, eg `John Smith` or `John Michael Smith`.

I have to write a query that returns records containing all words in the name presented. So query will return records that has the name of all those words, but may have different order.

For example, if the search string is `John Michael Smith`, the query should be able to return records with names like `Michael John Smith`, `Michael Smith John`, `John Smith Michael` or some combination of all these words there. As can be seen only return records that still has all the words in the name field, but may have different order. However, it should return results that do not contain part of the name, for example, `John Michael` should not be returned because it does not have `Smith` in there.

I tried query like this:

```
SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE
     name LIKE '%Michael%' &&
     name LIKE '%Smith%' &&
     name LIKE '%John%'
```

The same problem happens with:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name)
    AGAINST ('+Michael +Smith +John' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Both queries also returns `John Michael` instead of records that contain all three words :(

I can not figure out how to write a query to the requirement so that I have. Please help.

Comment: Your data in the database is not fully normalized. You need to create a field that stores a word individually per name (if a name consists of words), so you can select the individual word. You then only return all name entries that have matching word entries for all three words. This also saves you from saving the same text over and over again into the database.

Comment: @hakre: Table is normalized, it has `name` field which could contains full name.

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory: "some combination of all these words" v.s. "does not have Smith in there". Combinations also include subsets of the search terms.

Comment: @MarcB: I have not explained it well probably but result should return all records that have all words irrespective of the order. Thanks

Comment: no wait, something wrong upthere. The first query you posted can't return John Michael.

Comment: @Gianps: It does return, you can try it out on your own :)

Comment: @Dev555 if that is your query it CAN'T return John Michael.

Comment: @Gianps: as i said it does :(

Comment: I think your mysql server is fooling you, i tried it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). That's the easiest/quickest method. Otherwise you're stuck parseing your search string, converting

```
John Michael Smith
```

into

```
SELECT ... WHERE (name LIKE '%John%') OR (name LIKE '%Michael%') OR (name LIKE '%Smith%')
```

which very quickly gets painful to do, and VERY slow to perform, as `LIKE %..%` searches cannot use indexes.

Note that Fulltext indexes are currently restricted to MyISAM tables, so if you're on InnoDB, you'll have to use workarounds (parallel tables in MyISAM format to hold the searchable data with triggers to keep the two copies synchronized). Apparently Fulltext for InnoDB is **FINALLY** in the development pipeline, but it's not here yet.

Comment: Yes, well, at the time I wrote this up, OP hadn't updated his post with his query attempts yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you save the name in the field 'name' your sql query should be like this

first explode the string by space

```
$params = explode(' ', $input_name);
```

then append this on your query:

```
    $i = 0;
    $q= '';
    foreach($params as $p){
        $p = strtolower($p);
        if($i > 0) $q.= " and ";
        $q.= "LOWER(name) like '%$p%'";
        $i++;
    }

$query="select .... where ".$q;
```

the lower things are needed to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

